# read() returning bad address once nested

Tags: c

I am writing a simple shell program that must take input from a file one character at a time using the read() function in C. The read() function is the only way I want to take input from the user. I can get this part to operate properly in a very simple like this one:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
int error = 0;
int input_result = 1; /*Integer to track the result of inputs.*/
int input_exit = 0;
char input_buffer[100];
char *buffer_pointer = &input_buffer[0];
char *input;

write( 1, "# ", 2 ); /*Display # to signal the user to input data.*/

int input_counter = 0; /*Int that tracks the number of input characters.*/

/*While loop to continually take input from the user.*/
/*Step one of the programming assignment.*/
while( input_exit == 0 && input_result == 1 && input_counter < 15 && error == 0)
{
    input_result = read( 0, input, (size_t) 1 );

    input_buffer[input_counter] = *input;

    printf( "%c - %d\n", input_buffer[input_counter], input_result );

    input_counter++;
} /*End while for user input*/

write( 1, input_buffer, (size_t) input_counter );
}
```

Using my input file, which is also very simple I get the proper output with no errors what so ever. Once I start to make the code more complicated and add some nested while loops I start to receive the "Bad address" error. The code that is throwing the error can be seen below. As a side note, I do realize my C programming is not the greatest overall and there are things I could change, however I would like to just focus on the issues with read. Thank you in advance for your assistance it is greatly appreciated.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
/*Infinite loop to keep the shell running until it is implicitly ended by the user.*/
while( 1 )
{
    int error = 0; /*Int to keep track if an error occurred.*/

    char input_buffer[101]; /*Array of chars to hold the input.*/
    char *input_bufferp = &input_buffer[0]; /*Pointer to the first element of the char array.*/
    char *input; /*Char pointer to hold the read input*/
    char *newline = "\n";
    int buffer_counter = 0; /*Int that tracks the number of input characters.*/
    int input_result = 1; /*Int to hold the result of the read.*/

    char input_string[17][64]; /*Array to the parsed input data.*/
    char **input_stringp; /*Pointer to the first element of the string array.*/
    char *input_strings; /*Holds the parsed information before it is organized.*/
    int string_counter = 0; /*Int to track the number of strings.*/


    write( 1, "# ", 2 ); /*Display # to signal the user to input data.*/

    /*While loop to parse the information into separate strings.*/
    /*This while loop contains steps 1 and 2.*/
    while( string_counter == 0 && error == 0)
    {
        /*While to take in information via read.*/
        while( buffer_counter < 100 && input_result == 1 )
        {
            input_result = read( 0, input, (size_t) 1 ); /*Read one char from the user.*/

            /*If statement to signal an input error.*/
            if( input_result == -1 )
            {
                error = 1; /*Signal the error*/
                printf( "\nInput errno: %s\n", (char *)strerror(errno) ); /*Inform the user of the error.*/

                exit(0);
            }/*End if to signal an error.*/

            /*If to handle the end of the file.*/
            else if( input_result == 0 )
            {
                input_buffer[buffer_counter] = '\0'; /*Place the escape char.*/
            }/*End if for end of file.*/

            /*If statement handles a proper read from the user.*/
            else if( input_result == 1 )
            {
                /*If statement to check for a new line.*/
                if( strcmp( input_bufferp[buffer_counter], newline ) == 0 )
                {
                    input_result = 0; /*Set variable to exit the while loop.*/
                    input_buffer[buffer_counter] = '\0'; /*Place the escape char.*/
                }/*End new line if.*/

                /*Else statement to put input into the buffer.*/
                else
                {
                    input_buffer[buffer_counter++] = *input; /*Place the input into the buffer.*/
                }/*End buffer else.*/
            } /*End good input read.*/
        } /*End input gather while loop.*/

        write( 1, input_bufferp, (size_t) buffer_counter ); /*Echo the input to the user*/

        input_strings = strtok( input_bufferp, " \t" ); /*Split the input into tokens.*/

        /*While loop to tokenize the rest of the data.*/
        while( input_strings != NULL )
        {
            input_stringp[string_counter++] = input_strings; /*Store the tokenized string.*/
            input_strings = strtok( NULL, " \t" ); /*Spilt the remain data into tokens.*/
        } /*End tokenizer while loop.*/

        input_stringp[string_counter--][0] = '\0'; /*Please the escape char.*/
    } /*End parsing while loop.*/

    /*Check if the user wants to exit.*/
    if( strncmp( *input_stringp, "exit", 4 ) == 0 )
    {
        exit( 0 ); /*Exit the shell.*/
    } /*End if to exit program.*/


} /*End of infinite while loop.*/
}
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? which settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the value of a variable until you set it to some value. You never initialize `input` to point to anything and then you pass its value to `read`, reading data to no place in particular.

The second parameter to `read` tells `read` where to store the data. It must point to some space that you have allocated to store one or more characters, which your code never does.

Change `input` to be a `char`, not a `char *`. That will allocate space to store ono character. Then pass the *address* of `input` to `read`.